# Permissions denied when trying to invoke Go AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've created a AWS Lambda function that I'm using a Webhook to call an [API Gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgyED.png) Below is the code I've built with `go build -o main.go` since I've been reading that you have to specify the extension.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context) (string, error) {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Hello!"), nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
```

The issue is even though I have [public permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh8Ql.png) on my uploaded [S3 function .zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixTE3.png) as well as [role permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQJdo.png) I'm still getting a permissions error.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "fork/exec /var/task/main: permission denied",
  "errorType": "PathError"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to run the go source code file.  You need to run the binary:

```sh
# Build the binary for your module
GOOS=linux go build main.go

# Package the binary, note we're packaging "main", not "main.go" here:
zip function.zip main

# And upload "function.zip" this package to Lambda
```

For more details, including directions to run through this process on other platforms, see the [AWS Lambda Deployment documentations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-go-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)

Also, you'll need to set the executable bit in the zipfile.  There are a bunch of ways to do this, if you want to do it on Windows, you'll need to run a python script like this:

```py
import zipfile
import time

def make_info(filename):
    info = zipfile.ZipInfo(filename)
    info.date_time = time.localtime()
    info.external_attr = 0x81ed0000
    info.create_system = 3
    return info

zip_source = zipfile.ZipFile("source_file.zip")
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile("dest_file.zip", "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

for cur in zip_source.infolist():
    zip_file.writestr(make_info(cur.filename), zip_source.open(cur.filename).read(), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

zip_file.close()
```

This will take a `source_file.zip` and repackage it as `dest_file.zip` with the same contents, but with the executable bit set for all of the files.

Comment: I understand it looks like it's the binary, but it's actually the built application, I was following this: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/274#issuecomment-362608391 But after I remove the .go it's still giving me this error after `go build `go build -o main main.go`

`
{
  "errorMessage": "fork/exec /var/task/main: permission denied",
  "errorType": "PathError"
}
`

Comment: Ahh, I see.  What platform did you build the zip file on, and what do the permissions in the zip file look like?

Comment: Unfortunately windows, and it seems I have full permissions on the zip as well as the built go application: https://ibb.co/F0BH7JR

Comment: Fair enough, you'll need to set the executable bit on the executable as well.  Doing it on Windows is tricky, I edited in a small python script that does that, which might be a useful starting point.

Comment: I don't fully understand the "executable bit" can you explain?

Comment: Unix [file perms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions) control if a file can be read, written, and unlike Windows if they can be executed.  The Python example I showed sets the file mode to "755" (0x81ed0000 in external_attr ) and the source OS to Unix (the 3 in create_system).  The net result is when the Lambda container unpacks any file it'll be marked executable so your main executable can be run by the engine that launches it.  It's a bit of a hack because most Windows zip programs ignore the external_attr bits, which end up being converted to read/write only by unix.

Comment: You answer lead me to the answer on Windows. I had to carefully follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-package.html#golang-package-windows and blam, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when I tried to invoke serverless function locally, I disabled selinux temporarily and I invoked the function and it's worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you got to make sure the name of the binary is similar to the handler's name. That should be your case already:

```
$ unzip -l main.zip 
Archive:  main.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
 21477357  11-13-2020 00:02   main
```

More tricky though you should make sure the binary has the right permissions, as  Anon Coward highlighted in a comment:

```
$ ls -l bin/main 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 19325838 nov.  12 03:23 bin/main
```

That should make your binary executable.

In my case I could not `chmod 755` the binary because I was working in an Ubuntu VM under a shared folder mounted in the VM so I ended up with these perms and I could not change them:

```
$ ls -l bin/main 
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 19325838 Nov 12 02:23 bin/main
```

I would be curious to know why I could not change the group and the perms on the file inside the vm, if someone has an answer.